# What is the umbrella term for examination/diagnostics using tools, equipment and instruments?

Tags: terminology, diagnostics

There's a Russian healthcare term **[инструментальная диагностика](https://www.multitran.com/m.exe?a=3&sc=8&s=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&l1=2&l2=1)** - instrumental diagnostics (I'm not sure whether the translation provided by Multitran is really commonly used in English).

It covers all diagnostical procedures carried out using any kinds of tools: ECG, MRI, X-ray, blood pressure monitors, treadmills, angiography tools, as opposed to questioning the patient verbally or taking a blood test.

What is the English umbrella term for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "instrumental diagnostics" is commonly used in Russian and Eastern European texts and it appears as such in texts translated into English (search results for ["instrumental diagnostics"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22instrumental%20diagnostics%22&ei=RFWLXdzCOMbRwALO-6rAAQ&start=50&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjc9Ovu9OvkAhXGKFAKHc69Chg4KBDy0wMIcw&biw=1280&bih=918)).

The term instrumental diagnostics is rarely used by English authors and its equivalent is "investigations," which includes laboratory tests, imaging and other investigations. Sometimes, laboratory tests are mentioned separately as ["laboratory tests and investigations"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22laboratory%20tests%20and%20investigations%22&ei=VluLXdvyIsHewALBkbWAAQ&start=0&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjb9dbT-uvkAhVBL1AKHcFIDRA4FBDy0wMIdw&biw=1280&bih=918).

So, the umbrella term for "instrumental diagnostics" could be simply **investigations** or, more precisely, **clinical investigations**.

Examples:

- "History-taking and physical examination versus investigations" (the title of one section of [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5209934/))
- "Basics of the Health History, Physical Examination, and Clinical Investigations" (the title of [this article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118783283.ch1))

"Investigations" do not include using simple tools, such as the stethoscope and blood pressure monitor, during *physical examination.*